# l18n translation using "on" as part of the key not working? Is it a keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I'm trying to use the i18n translate (t) method to translate a string. I can get it work with any key I can think of except the word "on". Am I colliding with a keyword?

For now, I'll just give give the key a different name so we can have our Rails app be in more than one language. I was just curious because I couldn't find any documentation about it.

We're using postgres as the db if that makes any difference. I don't really know how the i18n class works.

Comment: How exactly are you using `t` when it doesn't work? What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: trushkevich solved the issue. It had to do with parsing YAML.

But here's what I was seeing: When you call the translate function t(key) it tries to look up that key in the YAML. If it can't find that key, it just converts the key name to a string (and capitalizes it) without any translation. If used in the view it also wraps the returned string in a span  <span class="translation_missing"> to help you notice that there was a t() error.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to how YAML works.

```
require 'yaml'

YAML::load("yes: Yes\nno: No")
# => {true=>true, false=>false}

YAML::load("on: Yes\noff: No")
# => {true=>true, false=>false}

YAML::load("on: Yes text\noff: No text")
# => {true=>"Yes text", false=>"No text"}
```

So in fact after parsing YAML there is no `'yes'` key. That's why your translation can't be found. However you can specify data type explicitly:

```
YAML::load("!!str on: Yes text\noff: No text")
# => {"on"=>"Yes text", false=>"No text"}
```

or just write a key inside quotation marks:

```
YAML::load("'on': Yes text\noff: No text")
# => {"on"=>"Yes text", false=>"No text"}
```

You can find some more detailed explanation [here](http://juliankniephoff.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/reserved-words-in-yaml-and-translating-booleans-in-rails/) and of course you can read the [specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html).

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm a more educated YAML user!
Additionally, I could write... "no": instead of !!str on: and the YAML parser will understand that "no" is a string and not a boolean.

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot to mention that. Updated my answer to include this option too.